# How to use discovery groups in ActiveMQ Artemis client connection?

Tags: kubernetes, jms, activemq-artemis

I need some help with the correct setting for using the client connection to a ActiveMQ Artemis broker cluster.

My goal here is to run a performance test against what I believe is our Artemis cluster. While testing I would like to kill some nodes and expect the performance test to continue.

First the cluster setup:

We are about to migrate to the new Artemis Cloud and have deployed [the Artemis operator](https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-operator) in our Kubernetes cluster. It is configured to run with three nodes at the moment.

`broker.xml`:

```xml
<connectors>
  <connector name="artemis">tcp://msc-test-ss-0.msc-test-hdls-svc.it.svc.cluster.local:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<acceptors>
  <acceptor name="msc-test">
    tcp://msc-test-ss-0.msc-test-hdls-svc.it.svc.cluster.local:61616?protocols=AMQP,CORE,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE,STOMP;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpMinCredits=300
  </acceptor>
</acceptors>

<cluster-user>SOME_USER</cluster-user>

<cluster-password>SOME_PASSWORD</cluster-password>

<broadcast-groups>
  <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
    <jgroups-file>jgroups-ping.xml</jgroups-file>
    <jgroups-channel>activemq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
    <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
  </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<discovery-groups>
  <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
    <jgroups-file>jgroups-ping.xml</jgroups-file>
    <jgroups-channel>activemq_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
    <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
  </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<cluster-connections>
  <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
    <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
    <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
    <retry-interval-multiplier>2</retry-interval-multiplier>
    <max-retry-interval>32000</max-retry-interval>
    <initial-connect-attempts>20</initial-connect-attempts>
    <reconnect-attempts>10</reconnect-attempts>
    <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
    <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
    <max-hops>1</max-hops>
    <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
  </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

`jgroups-ping.xml`:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd"
        >
    <TCP bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr:site_local}"
         bind_port="${jgroups.bind_port:7800}"
         external_addr="${jgroups.external_addr}"
         external_port="${jgroups.external_port}"
         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="200"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>
    <RED/>

    <dns.DNS_PING
            dns_query="msc-test-ping-svc"
            dns_record_type="${DNS_RECORD_TYPE:A}" />

    <MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
             max_interval="30000"/>
    <FD_SOCK2/>
    <FD_ALL3 timeout="40000" interval="5000" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT2 timeout="1500"  />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false" />
    <UNICAST3 />
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"/>
    <UFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
</config>
```

Now the command I am testing with:

```
/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin/artemis perf client --user user --password password --show-latency --url="tcp://msc-test-hdls-svc:61616?reconnectAttempts=5&confirmationWindowSize=20000" --consumer-url="tcp://msc-test-hdls-svc:61616?reconnectAttempts=5" queue://performance #--hdr case-1-new.hdr
```

Running the command outputs some performance stats and it seems that the client has successfully connected to a broker:

```
Connection brokerURL = tcp://msc-test-hdls-svc:61616?reconnectAttempts=5&confirmationWindowSize=20000

--- warmup false 
--- sent:           281 msg/sec 
--- blocked:        281 msg/sec 
--- completed:      281 msg/sec 
--- received:       282 msg/sec 
--- send ack time:   mean:   3325.25 us - 50.00%:    679.00 us - 90.00%:   1687.00 us - 99.00%:  81407.00 us - 99.90%:  83455.00 us - 99.99%:  83455.00 us - max:     83455.00 us 
--- transfer time:   mean:   3402.32 us - 50.00%:    787.00 us - 90.00%:   4015.00 us - 99.00%:  78335.00 us - 99.90%:  83455.00 us - 99.99%:  83455.00 us - max:     83455.00 us
```

Now when killing a node, I receive the following warning:

```
2023-06-14 12:56:47,361 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to msc-test-hdls-svc/10.4.1.113:61616 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
```

After that stats keep being printed, but are all `0 msg/sec`.

Then after some more time:

```
2023-06-14 12:57:52,312 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212036: Can not find packet to clear: 3 last received command id first stored command id 0
```

And the pod running the command is restarted.

My expectation here is that the client will attempt to connect to a different node now after it discovered that one node has been killed.

Either my expectations are wrong or something in my setup isn't working. Any help?

EDIT: I also tried using multiple client IPs in the connection string, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't have [high availability](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html) configured which means that when a broker fails the client will not fail-over to a backup.

In 2.29.0 this will be different as fail-over to another live broker will be supported via [ARTEMIS-4251](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4251).

Comment: In my words: If we configure HA this would work because the backup node would switch positions with the live node? And if we wait it would with the current configuration?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head if it would work if you just waited. However, I believe it would work if you configured HA.

Comment: Seems to work with pooled connections via https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms

Comment: What exactly is working with `pooled-jms`? I thought you were using the `artemis perf client` command. Did you somehow get this to work with a connection pool?

Comment: I mixed up things. Apologies. `artemis perf` uses the client library which alone doesn't work. I discovered I had inconsistencies between `artemis perf` and our own client library. It seems that in our company's client library we have implemented application-layer failover which doesn't suffer from killing live nodes in the cluster (and we implement `pooled-jms`).